# How to see the results of `whatsThis` in a tree view in Qt

Tags: qt

I re-implement the `data()` method in `QAbstractItemModel` and return a string when role is `Qt::WhatsThisRole` there. However, how can I see the box showing the `whatsThis` text? I put the mouse on an item in the tree view, enter `shift + F1`, no results is shown. Anything else I need to do in code and/or operation? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Qt::WhatsThisRole provides only the string for a certain row/column/cell in your view. You have to enable WhatsThisMode.  static QWhatsThis::enterWhatsThisMode(); Your shift+F1 does not seem to do this by default.